# Python - moving final data to a new sheet

Tags: python

I wrote the following code where when I print it I can see the output/final result of the program, but I want to have my final result as a column in a separate python sheet.

```
with (open('IBM.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as infile,
          open('IBM_out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile):
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=['Change'])
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            row['Close']
            row['Change'] = (float(row['Close']) - float(row['Open'])) / float(row['Open'])

            print(row['Change'])
```

I want to see the "Change" column in the "IBM_out.csv" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me if this works for you.

```
import csv
with (open('IBM.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as infile,
          open('IBM_out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile):
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
        fieldnames = reader.fieldnames + ['Change']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            row['Close']
            row['Change'] = (float(row['Close']) - float(row['Open'])) / float(row['Open'])

            writer.writerow(row)
```